# Presenting multiple, average-sized images on mobile devices using little vertical space

Tags: website-design

I hope this question has its place here. I'm adapting my client's resort website for mobile devices. On a resort page, there's the hotel name, then below it its pictures, then the package description, then a call to action button. The pictures are important but we don't want them to occupy too much vertical.

The big problem is the pictures are only 400px wide. So they can fill the page width as part of a slider only in smartphones smaller than that. However on greater resolutions, how to present these pictures so that it looks professional but doesn't eat much vertical space?

Answer (score 1):

400px seems to be wide enough for any smartphone out there right now. In most cases, like e.g.  iPhone, the actual width of the screen is considered to be 320 logical pixels and then everything is scaled twice in order to fill the high DPI screen. In this particular case, there should be no eye-visible quality loss.

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio

As it's an obvious goal to display the call to action button without a need for scrolling, I would recommend using a slider with autochange enabled, so the pictures won't take to much vertical space, and the user wil see more than one photo either he interacts with the slider or not.